How to implement UM7 IMU in ros2_control
In my current setup I have a working robot that can drive with ros2_control(diff_drive_controller & joint_state_broadcaster) and my own written Hardware Component: diffdrive_roboteq.
I am now trying to implement an IMU sensor: UM7.
I am however not quite sure on how to implement the sensor. I currently have a launch file where I can access the sensor, but get nonsense as output. I also have tried using the IMU Sensor Broadcaster but am struggling to get this to work. Underneath I will post my files.
Thanks in advance :D
um7.launch.py:
def generate_launch_description():
    parameters = LaunchConfiguration('parameters')

    arg_parameters = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'parameters',
        default_value=PathJoinSubstitution([
          FindPackageShare('my_robot'),
          'config',
          'redshift_um7.yaml'
        ]))

    umx_driver_node = Node(
        package='umx_driver',
        executable='um7_driver',
        parameters=[parameters],
        output='screen',
        remappings=[
            ('imu/data', 'data'),
            ('imu/mag', 'mag'),
            ('imu/rpy', 'rpy'),
            ('imu/temperature', 'temperature'),
        ]
    )

    ld = LaunchDescription()
    ld.add_action(arg_parameters)
    ld.add_action(umx_driver_node)
    return ld

broadcaster_spawner
imu_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["imu_broadcaster", 
                   "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    delayed_imu_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[imu_broadcaster_spawner],
        )
    )

my_controllers.yaml:
imu_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
    sensor_name: um7_driver
    frame_id: imu_link

output when starting um7.launch.py:
[um7_driver]: um7_driver successfully connected to serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[um7_driver]: Discarding packet due to bad checksum.
[um7_driver]: Discarded 34 junk byte(s) preceeding packet.
[um7_driver]: Received packet 02 without data.
[um7_driver]: Setting update rate to 30Hz
[um7_driver]: Received packet 02 without data.
[um7_driver]: Received packet 02 without data.
[um7_driver]: Received packet 04 without data.
[um7_driver]: Received packet 05 without data.
[um7_driver]: Received packet 06 without data.
[um7_driver]: Received packet 08 without data.
[um7_driver]: Sending command: zero gyroscopes
[um7_driver]: Received packet ad without data.

output when starting robot launch file with imu_broadcaster
[controller_manager]: Loading controller 'imu_broadcaster'
[spawner_imu_broadcaster]: Loaded imu_broadcaster
[controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'imu_broadcaster'
[controller_manager]: Can't activate controller 'imu_broadcaster': State interface with key 'um7_driver/orientation.x' does not exist
[spawner_imu_broadcaster]: Configured and activated imu_broadcaster
```


The IMU sensor broadcaster needs a hardware component, which exports the correct data as state interfaces.
The driver you linked is a simple ROS node publishing the data as ROS topic, it's not a hardware component for ros2_control. You'd need to rewrite it, see this tutorial here.
What do you want to do with your data then? Maybe you can use the driver as it is.

We have discussed this internally and have decided that we want to keep it inside of ros2_control. I have already started with rewriting the driver as a hardware component, but am struggling with how to access the hardware component inside the IMU sensor broadcaster.

For ease, I have created another question
